# Unable to compare to date[Local date and server date]

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am try to compare two date-

dateArrayForCompare, is the date which i get from NSDate and, dateArrayServer, is the date which i get from json response.

```
 var dateArrayServer = NSMutableArray()
 var dateArrayCalendar = NSMutableArray()
 var dateArrayForCompare = NSMutableArray()



let dateHomework:NSArray = allAsign.valueForKey("date") as! NSArray
 let homeWork = allAsign.valueForKey("assignmenttype") as! NSArray       

for date in dateHomework{
self.dateArrayServer.addObject(date as! String)
         }


let sys_date = NSDate()
                        print("System Date: \(sys_date)")
                        let df = NSDateFormatter()
                        df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
                        let currentDate = df.stringFromDate(sys_date)
                        print("String Date: \(currentDate)")

                        for dt in 0...self.dateArrayServer.count-1
                        {
                            if(self.dateArrayServer.objectAtIndex(dt) .isEqualToString("\(self.dateArrayForCompare)"))
                            {
                                print("Assignment on date: \(self.dateArrayServer.objectAtIndex(dt)) are:\n\(allAsign.objectAtIndex(dt))")
                            }else
                            {
                                print("\(self.dateArrayServer.objectAtIndex(dt)) doesn't match with \(self.dateArrayForCompare) ")
                            }
                        }
```

But get this result-

[image]

Comment: You compare a single string with (the string representation of) an array of strings, those cannot be equal.

Comment: `let elements = [self.dateArrayForCompare]
        if elements.contains(dateArrayServer) {
            print("Date Matched")
            
        }`

Comment: Unable to handle with **contains** also

Comment: You should compare **dateArrayServer.objectAtIndex(dt)** with each element in **dateArrayForCompare**

Comment: can you plz share code snippet @ĐinhQuangHiếu

Comment: How to overcome with this @MartinR

Comment: Posted code in the answer below

Comment: try to be more specific, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (swift 2.2)

```
for dt in 0 ... dateArrayServer.count-1
{
    let date1 = dateArrayServer.objectAtIndex(dt) as! String
    for value in dateArrayForCompare.enumerate() {
        if date1 == value.element as! String {
            print(date1)
        }
    }
}
```